# Hiding specific desktop item via command line

Tags: command-line, cmd, icons, desktop

I need the command to hide *specific* icons from my desktop via command line.

Whenever I hide an icon manually, it will return after the next login due to company settings which I cannot override. Therefore I need a script which is started after every login.

I want to delete the "computer" and "user's files" icons, but everywhere I search I only find help for hiding all of them.

Edit: Forgot to mention I am using Windows 7 Professional. 
Searched a bit more for solutions online, still haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. The needed hint was given here: 
http://afidence.com/afd-blog/information-technology-support/afidence-windows-script-tip-by-david-rice-registry-keys-for-hidding-desktop-icons-in-windows-7/

My script now looks like this:

```
REM hide Computer icon on the desktop
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel" /v "{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
REM hide User's Files icon on the desktop
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel" /v "{59031a47-3f72-44a7-89c5-5595fe6b30ee}" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me, does icon mean .ink file?

If it is, you can use this following line :

> attrib +h computer.ink
>   attrib +h user's_file.ink

I am not sure about the .ink files' name, so you have to change it.

Just save these two lines as a .bat file and create a .ink file and put it to the startup folder.

Comment: I assume, you mean `.lnk`, not  `.ink` ?

Comment: I don't know how the "files" are called. AFAIK there are no files at all, at least my desktop folder doesn't show any (hidden files included). 
It is more of a Windows setting I need to change, not a file setting. Otherwise I could have deleted them easily.

Comment: try also `C:\users\public\desktop` (a hidden directory). Notes: It may be called differenty in other languages. You may not have write permission to this directory.

Comment: Nothing in there either.

Answer (score -1):

its much easier to hide desktop files by typing into cmd or batch file:

cd Desktop

attrib +h

to show again type:

cd Desktop

attrib -h

into cmd

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) can help you write answers that will be accepted and upvoted.